# capture panic into string variable

Tags: go

I have an unusual request. I need a way to convert the panic that I captured to string so I can save it. I have captured panic with recover() but it can't be converted to string because it is an interface that is runtime.boundError type. Does anyone know how can I save panics into string var for future use?

Comment: fmt.Sprintf("%v", recover())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `type assertion` . using type assertion you can check if an interface (in this case runtime.BoundError as you said) is of a specific type .
and it is generally used to make sure that an interface value satisfies another interface or to find the concrete type of the interface.

check this playground . you can assert it into `string` type .
https://go.dev/play/p/b6EtGrh0gGj

Comment: I tried to assert it but it made it panic again with the interface is not type string but runtime.boundsError. However, I did manage to save it with this line: 
string(r.(runtime.Error).Error(). It doesn't have stack trace but for my use case it is enough. Thank you